# How do I get only one answer to display in simple C++ calculator?

Tags: visual-c++

I am a novice programmer here so please be kind:

I am writing a C++ program that performs simple arithmetic. I have everything syntactically correct, but multiple answers are showing up e.g. each of my separate cout statements after after the answer is computer show up when + is used, but the subsequent cout statements as other operators are used (-, *, /) show only a few of them. I could use the help here is the code.

```
//This program will take two integers and compute them in basic arithmetic
//in the way that a simple calculator would.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    double sum, difference, product, quotient;
    char operSymbol;

    cout << "Please enter the first number you would like to equate: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Please enter the second number: ";
    cin >> num2;

    cout << "Please choose the operator you would like to use (+, -, *, /): ";
    cin >> operSymbol;
    switch (operSymbol)
    {
    case '+':
            sum = num1 + num2;
            cout << "The sum is: " << sum << endl;
    case '-':
            difference = num1 - num2;
            cout << "The difference is: " << difference << endl;
    case '*':
            product = num1 * num2;
            cout << "The product is: " << product << endl;
    case '/':
            quotient = num1 / num2;
            cout << "The quotient is: " << quotient << endl;
    }
system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly end the execution of code under every `case` label. Otherwise it *falls through* to the next `case`. You need to use `break`, which will *jump out* of `switch`:

```
case '+':
        sum = num1 + num2;
        cout << "The sum is: " << sum << endl;
        break;                                    // <-- end of this case
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `break` statements at the end of each case; otherwise, the execution of the program proceeds with the next case.  That's why you see all cases processed when you are handling the `+` case.  The `break` statement ends execution of the nearest enclosing loop or conditional statement in which it appears.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `break;` at the end of each case in your switch statement.